# Joining INT column to comma separated list of INTs

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL Server 2008, and trying to run some queries on some poorly stored data that I'd rather not go through and try to clean up (millions of rows to deal with). What I have is a log table with some FK data as a comma-separated string in one table, and an integer PK in another table. I'd like to be able to join the FK list of integers to the proper PK ints in the primary table. My query is something like this:

```
SELECT
    L.*
FROM MyLogs L (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Details D (NOLOCK) ON L.SearchValue = D.ID
```

In the above query, L.SearchValue contains "123,456,7890", while D.ID is an integer primary key. Is there any way to join these together in any sort of efficient manner, or should I just accept my fate and start working on a script to break all of these comma separated values into separate rows?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it's pretty much exactly as I expected (as much as I hate to admit it). I'll work on that clean up script, and then cross my fingers. I'll probably end up using the script Stu suggested to do the conversions. Wish me luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one of these (modify to do cast to ints)

[T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor)

Then, you're down to

```
SELECT    
L.*
FROM MyLogs L (NOLOCK),    
Details D (NOLOCK) 
Where D.ID In fn_WhatEverYouCallYourSplitFunction(L.SearchValue, ',')
```

And no, that is not efficient. At all.

Answer (score 0):

Very very very bad design, and this will be very poor perfomance, but you can use CharIndex function

```
   Select L.*FROM MyLogs L (NOLOCK)    
     Join Details D (NOLOCK) 
         On CharIndex(Cast(D.ID as varChar(6)), L.SearchValue) > 0
```

And this will prodcude some false joins as 12 will be in '34, 312, 455'.  To eliminate these joins you have to make query even more complex, by including delimiter

```
    Select L.*FROM MyLogs L (NOLOCK)    
     Join Details D (NOLOCK) 
         On CharIndex(Cast(', ' + D.ID as varChar(6)) + ',', 
                             ', ' + L.SearchValue + ',') > 0
```

... But I'd recommend that you start working on a script to break all of these comma separated values into separate rows.

Comment: Not really. Say D.ID is 1, and L.SearchValue is "34199"?

Answer (score 0):

The script to break this horribly-stored data will ultimately be much more efficient than writing a hacky SQL query that attempts to join on those values. i'm not sure that a join is even the way to go. Probably some form of subquery would work better as plan A.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT L.*
FROM MyLogs L (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Details D (NOLOCK) ON CONTAINS(',' + L.SearchValue + ',', ',' + Convert(varchar,D.ID) + ',')
```

It will be horribly ineffecient, but unlike Daniels answer it wont break if lets say SearchValue contains (123,234,345) and D.ID is 23 (Which would be true for 2 rows)

Adding the commas fixes that.